# Review spring cleaning: performance improvements and responsive design

Tags: discussion, review, design, announcements, performance

This is just a heads-up that there's a lot of work underway right now on the Review system, mostly in the areas of cleanup and bug-fixing.

The review system we have now was originally built over the summer and fall of 2012. There've been many additions and refinements since then, but the core logic and UI haven't changed very much since then - and that's led to a lot problems and annoyances:

- **Scale:** At the start of July 2012, we'd logged just over 303 thousand suggested edits on Stack Overflow, with under a thousand a day being added; today that number is over 4.6 million, with on average 1.7K new ones each day. Queries that were *good enough* for a few hundred thousand records weren't doing so well anymore... Taryn & Nick have been digging through them and making substantial improvements to the performance - allowing pages like the dashboard and stats/activity to load quickly enough to be useful once again.
- **Layout:** In 2012, I was using... I think it was a Sprint Galaxy Nexus. It was impressive enough that I could even *load* /review on it, even if I had to scroll and zoom all over the page to do anything. Now folks have all manner of fancy devices; my current phone has nearly 4x the screen resolution, and like many of you I kinda expect pages to treat it as a first-class citizen. Aaron has been toiling away on trying to make review's layout responsive, with [a new design for the dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319317/counters-text-is-truncated-in-queue-on-localized-sites/322036#322036) released two days ago and some initial work on making the queues themselves responsive underway as well. There's a *lot* of work to do here before it'll be ready for release, but with the foundation laid by [last year's work on responsive themeing for all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) this is finally possible and I'm excited to see it taking shape!

That said, there's no thorough cleanup that doesn't stir up dust - so it's likely we'll break a few things here or there while we're making these updates. So if you see something behaving badly, [please call it out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug%20review): I'll do my best to track & respond.

As always, thank you all for your patience and support, and the amazing effort all of you put in to keep these sites operating day after day - we just build the tools, it's folks like you who build the site.

Comment: I think you might want to inform Aaron of [this easy bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322144/158100), if he hasn't seen it already.

Comment: We're on it, @rene - thanks!

Comment: Maybe as a part of the clean up, make sure you don't need a blood sacrifice for using the filters!

Comment: You talking about the quick filters from the dashboard, @Braiam? Good call...

Comment: This one specifically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322016/how-many-people-use-filters-in-the-review#comment338644_322016

Comment: Pretty sure our designer has the same screen size, @sjade - we'll get it right eventually